# PHP Fatal error when I access my localhost through my Network IP

Tags: php, apache

I have apache/mysql installed on my OSX ElCapitan. and I enabled virtual host in httpd.config file since I have so many projects on my systme and I want to access any of them at any time.

I my httpd-vhost.config file, I configured the first site as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "Users/me/Sites/test"
servername test.local
serveralias 192.168.1.20
.....

</VirtualHost>
```

and of course a record in /etc/hosts to redirect test.local to 127.0.0.1

Now, everything works fine when I put test.local in safari. But when I put 192.168.1.20, I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

I have no idea what is wrong.

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Just a wild guess: You have configured a db connection for 127.0.0.1 but not for 192.168.1.20

Answer (score 1):

There can be some reasons:

- path in document root looks bad. Try use absolute path, for example "/home/users/me/Sites/test"
- If on 127.0.0.1 it works ok, but on 192.168.1.20 not, so there can be enabled restrictions on connection from different IP.

Remember about apache reloading and cache clearing in website and browser. Always you can debug by `vardump` on argument of prepare function in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a mysql DB privileges issue. `user@localhost` may have access to the DB but not `user@192.168.1.20`. Try `GRANT`ing access to `user@192.168.1.20`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for the help

the problem was with the credentials to connect to the database. In my config file I have:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') { // test envirnonmet
    define("DB_USER", "x");
    define("DB_PASS", "x");
    define("DB_NAME", "y");
} else { // production site
    define("DB_USER", "p");
    define("DB_PASS","w");
    define("DB_NAME", "xyz");
}
```

The first line I changed it to:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' || strstr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],"192.168") ) {
```

And now both are working.